# Shutdown.exe - Change the path in registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry, shutdown

I have a problem with the registry. In my school are some trolls which create links and batch files to shutdown the computers of others by placing them into shared folders and giving them names similar to the files we should use (eg. "tcp.bat" or "tcp.java(.lnk)" instead of "tcp.java", which is hidden in a subdir so the students open the bad file).

To do this they all use `shutdown [args]` or `shutdown.exe [args]`. For my school I have written a program to stop this by modifying the `-t` argument to at least one minute so the students can get some help from a teacher. But now I have a problem:

I thought that there are entries in the registry which point to the complete path of shutdown.exe, but nothing. I searched for `shutdown.exe` and `shutdown`, but found noting pointing to the `shutdown.exe`. So now my question:

What do I have to change where to make using `shutodwn` or `shutdown.exe` points to my program instead of the shutdown.exe?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rather than figuring out how to intercept "their" shutdown.exe attempt and replace it with "your" version, you are probably better off to prevent the malicious users from being able to place the malicious files where innocent users might launch them. (That might not be easy on a shared machine, depending on what other restrictions you might have.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question you asked (spoiler - it wont solve your issue)...

open a command prompt and type:

```
 echo %PATH%
```

That list of directories is where Windows looks for executable files (after the current directory), working from left to right until it finds a matching `.exe` or fails. If you insert a folder into your users' PATH variable before `c:\windows\system32;` eg `c:\myscripts;c:\windows\system32;` your `c:\myscripts\shutdown.exe` will be found first.

You may need to update both the system, and each users PATH variables to ensure your shutdown.exe is found, **but** this can be easily defeated. There are several methods to shutdown a computer via script or compiled code or even `rundll32.exe`. Also this wont prevent absolute or relative paths to the real file. `Shutdown.exe` is just a convenience, its not core to Windows shutting down. That said, I wouldnt try tampering with the file itself, while you might get your version to "stick", its only a matter of time before windows replaces it with the original.

Personally I would seriously look at group or local policy (depending on your network) to just revoke shutdown permissions for the problem users. It doesn't matter if a user runs the exe, if they dont have permission to shutdown the machine, the operation will fail.

If you cant lock down the systems for whatever reason your options are pretty limited.

Maybe instead of writing a shutdown replacement, run a script on a schedule (or write a service etc) on your file server that scans for any suspect files like .lnk, or .bat files and deletes them (or better yet take ownership and revoke access to the file so you can inspect / log who created it/which computer etc) and take any action.

You could take this even further with some code by using a filesystem watcher on the shared folder (from the file server itself!) your application will be notified of each new filename created in pretty much realtime and you can take whatever action. (like turning off the attackers computer :)

Comment: I think adding a new PATH variable is the best way. Removing the permisssion to shutdown isnt helpful the victim shuts his own machine down. Its not the attacker (at least not directly). Atm the people arnt smart enough to use other ways like own code or the absolute path. :)

Comment: Changing the path will resolve your described problem, but just to clarify - i mean revoke shutdown permission for all your students - doesnt matter if they are the "attacker" or "victim" - neither type of student actually needs the shutdown permission. Based on past experaince, this is a much more robust solution that hoping students dont learn new tricks.

Comment: But they need to shutdown their system because the computers arnt running until 18 o clock (then a script shuts all remaining computers off), they have to turn it off after the work is done. If there will be any new tricks we coiuld change but for now its the best solution. Most of the students have their "tricks" from YouTube and dont have detailed information about absolute paths and such things :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Doug Deden's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1423929/shutdown-exe-change-the-path-in-registry#comment2149116_1423929) that this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and changing some access permissions is probably a better way. Since this may still have some value regardless, here is a possible alternative.

The path to `shutdown.exe` is not set in the registry, but in your `PATH` variable. `shutdown.exe` is located in `C:\Windows\System32`, which is listed in your `PATH` variable. In order to find this for yourself, you can run `where shutdown`.

One option is to name your program `shutdown.exe` or `shutdown.bat` in whatever location you prefer and then add that location to the **front** of the `PATH` variable.

When you then run `where shutdown`, you will see something like:

```
C:\my\path\shutdown.exe
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe
```

This list is in order of priority, so Windows will run the first item in the list unless otherwise specified. This would work to stop anyone who simply runs `shutdown -s -t 0`, but not anyone running `C:\Windows\system32\shutdown -s -t 0`.

### Further Reading

- [Where - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [Shutdown - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)