# Remote shutdown attack

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, process-hacker

Is it possible to attack a pc through local network ? Or from the isp ? A remote attack to shutdown the pc ?

My desktop have been shutting down for past few days, I suspect a local network attack.

No virus or malware found on the pc.

Comment: Anything in the system event logs?

Comment: Does it also happen when you don't have a network connected? Or while booted into secure mode? Then it is most likely something local, maybe some malware which was not detected

Comment: It is possible, and also very unlikely. The eventlog will tell you what happened though. If the computer was shutdown by a hacker, it will say that. If its a faulty PSU, it will state something like: The computer shutdown unexpectedly.

Comment: Event logs shows critical power loss, https://ibb.co/w6x2NPH

Comment: Changed what the power buttons do, also removed power button plug from motherboard

Comment: When the shutdowns started it was connected to the network and I found system files were modified were modified somehow, i suspect shutdown was modified or a different file/ process were created to shutdown the pc, how do I fix it ?

Comment: @MehdiHasan - How exactly did you determine system files were modified?  If system files are modified you should use Fresh Start to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score -2):

You are referring to a type of exploit that allows someone to send "something" to your ip. A Nuke exploit would result in your PC going offline, maybe stopping a certain service or perhaps (highly unlikely) shutting down. A Flood exploit would swamp a targeted service (perhaps HTTP webserver, a gaming server your run, ...) into giving up and becoming unresponsive but that would hardly shutdown your computer unless your BIOS maybe initiates a critical shutdown when it detects the CPU overheating limit is reached (configurable). Although many Nukers/Flooders exist they are pretty much harmless when you apply all security patches/updates for your OS and nowadays there are pretty much no more existing or freely available Nukers/Flooders for current OS's that would result in a instant & full shutdown. If there were, it would be big news. Many other things could be at play, if you're running an expired trial copy of Windows Server it will somewhat randomly shut itself down every 24h.

A sudden shutdown is most likely a problem with your hardware such as a defect RAM board. To find those you could run a full test from the BIOS and make sure the hardware is correctly working.

Comment: so how do i counter the attacks if it's a nuke/flooder attack somehow ?  what about a modified shutdown.exe ? or a new file/process created, here's a similar post https://superuser.com/questions/1423929/shutdown-exe-change-the-path-in-registry/1644270#1644270

Comment: so how do i counter the attacks if it's a nuke/flooder attack somehow? --> You would use a firewall, the windows build-in firewall does a pretty good job stopping stuff like that, unless you manually openend a port for a specific service. What Windows version are you running?
Can't comment on the modified shutdown.exe, there's a reason your host is shutting down, messing with that could cause permanent hardware problems when the root cause is an actual hardware issue.

Comment: windows firewall is on, using windows 10 insider preview dev channel. it shows on the screen that windows are shutting down, to check the power button, already removed it from the motherboard and disabled what power buttons do. device temperatures are, as usual, windows are stable too. I suspect it's a modified shutdown.exe/process or an attack from the local network/isp. And I'm living in a rented house, so the device could be tampered with, there were attacks on the desktop and Facebook account too few months ago.

Comment: Have you checked the power settings from Windows self? Going sleep/shutdown etc and all that. It's interesting you see it actually shutting down, granted, that -is- weird. I wouldn't suspect the ISP as such but perhaps (but it's a long shot) it could be an infected router but in that case we're talking MiTM style attacks with additional payload in your normal network traffic. All that is pretty advanced hardcore hacking to just "shutdown a computer randomly or grab someone's Facebook". Have you tried a second virusscanner and ran a full/deep virus scan?

Comment: Have you installed a lot of third party software? Games? Warez? Do you have roommates that have administrator access to the desktop? Remote Desktop access?

Comment: Resetting power option in windows didn't changed anything. Sleep/ hybrid shutdown is turned off, changing the settings didn't affected the shutdowns. Did scans with Malwarebytes, and microsoft virus/ rootkit removal softwares, and windows security. Not sharing the apartment with anyone, but shady house owners are very common. Also disabled the remote access after the attack. Yes a lot of softwares are installed, I don't suspect those because I have been using this windows for a while.

Comment: Somehow login password got leaked in the past, and there were tempering of the files before. Mitm attack or data intercepting could be done, there's an increased amount of surveillance where Im from. So if it's that kind of attack can the windows firewall do anything ? Or how to counter it ?

Comment: Change your password and obviously remove all unused user accounts is a good start. You could give https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VirtualBox/XFCE a shot if you are really concerned with local online surveillance. Whonix is a bit technical to run if you're not into tech but it does a pretty good job. You could also try TOR browser https://www.torproject.org/download/ . It's very easy to use.

Comment: Unless your system is set up to trust the mitm root certificates used to sign the on-the-fly generated certificates an attack is pretty hard to execute when the target/your desktop is using TLS/HTTPS encryption. Unless of course you are being surveilled by a "state". You could check which Certificate Authorities your system trusts versus the actual official list at: https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/microsoft/IncludedCACertificateReportForMSFT

Comment: how do i install and run sigcheck, to check all the installed certificates ? download the latest version but sigcheck command doesn't work

Comment: What error do you get? Following http://woshub.com/how-to-check-trusted-root-certification-authorities-for-suspicious-certs/ should work. It correctly showed 2 certs in my store that are not in the default list. You need to run ```sigcheck64.exe``` for Win10 64bit. You could also check file signatures with ```sigcheck -u -e c:\windows\system32\``` (https://www.thewindowsclub.com/sigcheck-unsigned-certificates-windows)